# What is the difference between a resourceVersion and a generation?

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes object metadata, there are [the concepts of `resourceVersion` and `generation`](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#metadata).  I understand the notion of `resourceVersion`: it is an optimistic concurrency control mechanism—it will change with every update.  What, then, is `generation` for?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

resourceVersion changes on every write, and is used for optimistic concurrency control

in some objects, generation is incremented by the server as part of persisting writes affecting the `spec` of an object.

some objects' `status` fields have an `observedGeneration` subfield for controllers to persist the generation that was last acted on.

Comment: Thank you; could I ask you to elaborate on your second sentence a bit?  Is this like a "checkpoint"—i.e. a controller, in order to realize the state requested by an incoming resource, may have to write it in two parts?  Like, "OK, I've completed phase 1, but I haven't really fully changed the `spec` yet"?

Comment: No, it's an easy way for a controller to recognize that nothing in the spec has changed that it has to react to. Without it, the controller has to track what the spec it last acted on looked like (in memory, which fails across restarts, or persisted somewhere, which fails when new defaulted fields are added). With it, the controller reads the object, compares generation to the persisted status.observedGeneration, and if they differ, acts on the spec and records the results in the status with the newly observed generation.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I hope this is my last question: couldn't the same be accomplished by looking at the `resourceVersion`, or, as light slowly starts to dawn, because the `resourceVersion` might change as a result of some non-`spec` field changing, it is not suitable for this?

Comment: exactly. resourceVersion changes because of the status changes, label/annotation changes, or other unrelated changes, that should not require a controller to react to a spec change

Answer (score 11):

In a `Deployment` context:

## In Short

`resourceVersion` is the version of a k8s resource, while `generation` is the version of the deployment which you can use to undo, pause and so on using `kubectl` cli.

Source code for `kubectl rollout`: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/rollout/rollout.go#L50

## The Long Version

#### resourceVersion

K8s server saves all the modifications to any k8s resource. Each modification has a version which is called `resourceVersion`.

k8s languages libraries provide a way to receive in real-time events of `ADD`, `DELETE`, `MODIFY` events of any resource. You also have `BOOKMARK` event, but let's leave that for a moment aside.

On any modification operation, you receive the new k8s resource with updated `resourceVersion`. You can use this `resourceVersion` and start a watch starting from this `resourceVersion`, so you won't miss any events between the time the k8s server sent you back the first response, until the watch has started.

- K8s doesn't preserve the history for every resource for ever. I think that it will save for 5m, but I'm not sure exactly.

`resourceVersion` will change after any modification of the object.

The reason of it's existence is to avoid concurrency problems where multiple clients try to modify the same k8s resource. This pattern is pretty common also in databases and you can find more info about it:

- Optimistic concurrency control (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)
- https://www.programmersought.com/article/1104647506/

---

#### observedGeneration

You didn't talk about it in your question but thats important piece of information we need to clarify before moving on to `generation`.

It is the version of the replicaSet which this deployment is currently tracking on.

When the deployment is still creating for the first time, this value won't exist (good discussion on this can be found here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47871).

This value can be found under `status`:

```
....
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
.....
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-02-07T19:04:17Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2021-02-07T19:04:17Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-02-07T19:04:15Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2021-02-07T19:17:09Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "deployment-bcb437a4-59bb9f6f69" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 3.    <<<--------------------
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

- p.s, from this article: https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-deployments-work/

> observedGeneration is equal to the deployment.kubernetes.io/revision annotation. It is the observedGeneration.

It looks correct because `deployment.kubernetes.io/revision` does not exist when the deployment is first created and not yet ready, and also it has the same value as `observedGeneration` when the deployment is updated.

---

#### generation

It represents the version of the "new" replicaSet which this deployment ***should*** track on.

When a deployment is created for the first time, the value of this will be equal to 1. When the `observedGeneration` will be set to `1`, it means that replicate set is ready (This question is not about how to know if a deployment was successful (or not) so I'm not getting into what is "ready", which is some terminology I created for this answer - but be sure that there are **additional** conditions to check if a deployment was successful or not).

Same goes for any change in the deployment k8s resource which will trigger re-deployment. the `generation` value will be incremented by 1, and then it will take some time until `observedGeneration` will be equal to `generation` value.

More info on `observedGeneration` and `generation` in the context of `kuebctl rollout status` (to check if a deployment "finished") from `kubectl` source code:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/a2d36ec6d62f756e72fb3a5f49ed0f720ad0fe83/pkg/polymorphichelpers/rollout_status.go#L75

```
if deployment.Generation <= deployment.Status.ObservedGeneration {
        cond := deploymentutil.GetDeploymentCondition(deployment.Status, appsv1.DeploymentProgressing)
        if cond != nil && cond.Reason == deploymentutil.TimedOutReason {
            return "", false, fmt.Errorf("deployment %q exceeded its progress deadline", deployment.Name)
        }
        if deployment.Spec.Replicas != nil && deployment.Status.UpdatedReplicas < *deployment.Spec.Replicas {
            return fmt.Sprintf("Waiting for deployment %q rollout to finish: %d out of %d new replicas have been updated...\n", deployment.Name, deployment.Status.UpdatedReplicas, *deployment.Spec.Replicas), false, nil
        }
        if deployment.Status.Replicas > deployment.Status.UpdatedReplicas {
            return fmt.Sprintf("Waiting for deployment %q rollout to finish: %d old replicas are pending termination...\n", deployment.Name, deployment.Status.Replicas-deployment.Status.UpdatedReplicas), false, nil
        }
        if deployment.Status.AvailableReplicas < deployment.Status.UpdatedReplicas {
            return fmt.Sprintf("Waiting for deployment %q rollout to finish: %d of %d updated replicas are available...\n", deployment.Name, deployment.Status.AvailableReplicas, deployment.Status.UpdatedReplicas), false, nil
        }
        return fmt.Sprintf("deployment %q successfully rolled out\n", deployment.Name), true, nil
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed...\n"), false, nil
```

I must say that I'm not sure when a `observedGeneration` can be higher than `generation`. Maybe folks can help me out in the comments.

---

To sum it all up: Illustration from this great article: https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-deployments-work/
[image]

More Info:

- https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/C2GL57FJ4/p1612651711106700?thread_ts=1612650049.105300&cid=C2GL57FJ4
- Some more information about Bookmarks Events (Which are related to `resourceVersion`: [What k8s bookmark solves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080942/what-k8s-bookmark-solves/66081227?noredirect=1#comment116833613_66081227)
- How do you rollback deployments in Kubernete: https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-rollbacks

Comment: "I must say that I'm not sure when a observedGeneration can be higher than generation. Maybe folks can help me out in the comments."


Rollbacks come to mind

Comment: "I must say that I'm not sure when a observedGeneration can be higher than generation. Maybe folks can help me out in the comments."

Could it be that after a restart, the watch observes the older version of resources?

Comment: @stav could you provide the source code where you see the generation of deployment is set to 1 by default? thanks