# What k8s bookmark solves?

Tags: kubernetes

#### What I'm Trying To Do

I'm trying to make a deployment and watch for k8s events until the deployment is ready using **k8s node api** (Watch): https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/typescript/watch/watch-example.ts

---

#### My Questions

I have read this section: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#watch-bookmarks over and over but I still can't understand, **from the client perspective**:

1. What is this feature try to solve?
2. When should I use it?
3. Can I not use it and not miss events?
4. How do I use it?
5. What should I do when I receive bookmark event.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer your questions from the client's perspective:

### What is this feature trying to solve?

Its intended to reduce the load on kube-apiserver from clients that issue Watch requests for a resource type. Bookmarks are intended to let the client know that the server has sent the client all events up to the `resourceVersion` specified in the Bookmark event. This is to make sure that if the watch on the client side fails or the channel closes (after timeout), the client can resume the watch from `resourceVersion` last returned in the Bookmark event. It's more like a checkpoint event in the absence of real mutating events like Added, Modified, Deleted.

The client could already be caching the resourceVersion that is received as part of the regular Added, Modified, Deleted events, but consider a case where the resource you're watching has had no updates in the last 30 minutes and the `resourceVersion` you have cached is "100".

In the absence of bookmark events, you will attempt to resume from "100", but the server could return a "410 Gone" indicating that it doesn't have that version or it is too old. In that case, the client will have to do a List to get the latest resourceVersion and initiate a watch from there or start the watch from latest by specifying no resourceVersion, which is more expensive for the server to process.

In the presence of bookmark events, the server might attempt to send you a Bookmark event with resourceVersion "150" indicating that you have processed up that version and in the event of a restart you can start processing from there onwards.
 
This contrived example in the documentation shows just that. You start your watcher at rv="10245", you process some events up to rv="10596" and then the server sends you a bookmark with rv="12746" so in the event of a restart you can start processing from there onwards.

```
GET /api/v1/namespaces/test/pods?watch=1&resourceVersion=10245&allowWatchBookmarks=true
---

200 OK 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "type": "ADDED",
  "object": {"kind": "Pod", "apiVersion": "v1", "metadata": {"resourceVersion": "10596", ...}, ...}
}
...
{
  "type": "BOOKMARK",
  "object": {"kind": "Pod", "apiVersion": "v1", "metadata": {"resourceVersion": "12746"} }
}
```

### When should I use it?

For efficient processing of change events on the resource your watching, it seems better to process Bookmarks than to not. There are no guarantees round the delivery of Bookmarks though - the server might not support it (if it is running an older version of Kubernetes), or it might not send them at all.

### Can I not use and not miss events?

Yes, you could totally do that, but your likelihood of missing events decreases if you use Bookmarks. Also remember that it not only benefits the client but also the kube-apiserver, because it could return events from its local cache if it has the "fresh" resourceVerion you received in a Bookmark, in the absence of which it will have to do a consistent-read from etcd. I recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLSDvFjR9HY) video to understand how Watch events work under the hood.

### How do I use it?

Depending on which client library you're suing the usage might be different, but in a raw HTTP request you can specify this query param: **allowWatchBookmarks=true**

```
GET /api/v1/namespaces/test/pods?watch=1&resourceVersion=10245&allowWatchBookmarks=true
```

If you're using [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go), there is a tool called Reflector, and [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/cache/reflector.go#L409) is how it requests bookmarks and [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/cache/reflector.go#L518) is how it processes it.

### What should I do when I receive a Bookmark event?

Extract the resourceVersion from the Bookmark event and cache it for when you try to restart your watcher for any reason.

Comment: it seems to me that this is the best answer here, though I want to ask a small clarification. suppose I am watching a pod and I get `resourceVersion=10` and `bookmark=100`. Does this mean that in the interval `[11..100]` there are no events specific to the resource I am watching, right? As such, in case of a restart it is safe for me to ask from `100`, since I am sure that below that I have either already consumed (`10` one) or there are no events for my resource(`11..100`). correct?

Comment: @Eugene correct.  Caveat when talking of “interval 11..100” : k8s versions presently look like numbers, but the API insist you should treat them as opaque strings.  So you may restart watch from exact versions you've seen — "100" (best), or "11" (higher risk of 410 Gone response), but you should not send e.g. "12" or "60".  So don't take “interval” literally as numeric interval, but it's an OK shorthand for “chronologic interval from version represented as `"11"` to version represented as `"100"`”.

Answer (score 3):

It’s about reconnect mechanism about List-Watch.
 When “watch” connection broken, it will do the reconnect and “resourceversion” is the start point which client need to tell the server(api-server), then the server will return all the event from the point.

But in general, client has filter, that’s means the “resourceverseion” in client side will not change if the event is not care by the client(for example kubelet only care resource in its node). And the etcd only keep 5 min event by default.

Think about one case, a kubelet has the “resourceversion=5” of resource pod, then the “resourceversion” increase in server side to 100 (since these change: 6 - 100 not care by the client, so the “resourceversion” in client side is still 5). Then connection broken, the reconnect start, client tell server its “resourceversion” is 5, but on server side the oldest “resourceversion” is 25, so the server have no idea, since it will cause event missing in client side, so it have to return error: too old version error. Then the client have to clean its cache and List-Watch again, it will cost much time.

With BookMark, the client will get notification(only latest “resourceversion”, no details for event) no matter it care or not when event raised, it make sure the “resourceversion” in client side is fresh. So it avoid to a new List-watch.

Seems Bookmark could reduce the List to 3% compare to no BookMark.

Comment: very good answer, thank you. I could not wrap my head around the reason of HTTP_GONE, but now it all makes sense, too.

Answer (score 2):

It allows resuming the watch efficiently because you know you've processed everything up to that point. The next time you start a watch you can use that as the starting version and not need to reply every object.

Comment: Thanks for the (really) quick answer but this answer miss a lot of details, very vague and ambiguous. For example: What do you mean by: "you've processed everything up to that point"? Did k8s sent me these events and then sent me additional event that tells me: "I have sent you all the events until resourceVersion `x`? What do you mean by: "The next time you start a watch"? Should I start a new watch? When? Does the k8s-client of node deals with it internally? What do I do when I receive this event? Can I not use it? will I miss events if I don't?

Comment: The JS Kubernetes library is very low-level, I don't know if it supports automatic re-connection. The Go library does though, using this feature. Watches are done over a single HTTP stream so if that disconnects for any reason, the client needs to connect again and it's much faster to reconnect using bookmarks.

Comment: can I safely not use this feature at all? (and not lose any events)?

Comment: Sure, when you reconnect a watch it will be just like a cold start and you'll get everything. Just will usually mean that you take longer to recover from a connection drop since you need to process all of those and at a minimum check if any action is needed.

Comment: so it seems like "bookmark" strategy is meant for: the k8s server knows which event was sent to which client, and after reconnect of one of the clients, the client MAY request bookmark events, and then the server MAY send back bookmark events which specify that this particular client already received all events up until specific_resource_revision. also, if other client will start his first watch for the same resourceRevision, it will NOT receive bookmark event, but it will receive all events from that specific resourceRevision?  Am I correct?!

Comment: @coderanger Could you please address this question?

Answer (score 0):

k8s will send to you two things, for example:

```
resourceVersion=100 (for ADDED event let's say)
resourceVersion=200 (for BOOKMARK event)
```

This means two things for you as the *client*. It's easier to understand if we break this into two pieces:

- `resourceVersion=100` for the resource that you are currently watching, is something that you care about. For example if you are watching Pods, then the `100` is a Pod ADDED event - thus you as a client will get that event.
- The second part means that in the interval `101..200` there are no events that you as the client, care about. So in case of a restart, its safe to start from 200: you either consumed everything in that range (`100` for example), or there are no events that you care about (`101..200`)