# How to check if k8s deployment is passed/failed manually?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to understand what does `kubectl rollout status <deployment name>` do.

I'm using k8s-node-api, and from this thread (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/issues/536), the maintainer suggest using k8s-watch api to watch for changes in the deployment, but I'm not sure what to check.

Questions:

1. How to make sure the new deployment succeed?
2. How to make the the new deployment failed?
3. Is it safe to assume that if the spec/containers/0/image changes to something different than what I'm expecting, it means there is a new deployment and I should stop watching?

- My questions are probably ambiguous because I'm new to k8s.

Any guidance will be great!

---

I can't use `Kubectl` - I'm writing a code that does that based on what `kubectl` does.

Comment: To check any object and processes in Kubernetes you have to use kubectl https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/ Take a look also https://github.com/kubernetes/node-api 

> The node-api group was migrated to a built-in API in the 
> [k8s.io/api](https://github.com/kubernetes/api)  repo with the v1.14 release.  **This repo is no longer maintained**, and no longer synced with core kubernetes as of the v1.18 release.

Also to check how rollout looks from backgroud look at the source code - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/rollout/rollout.go.

Comment: thanks @Malgorzata, I did my best to copy-paste the Go code to NodeJs code to check if deployment succeed or not.

Comment: So problem is solved ? Did my comment help ?

Comment: the GitHub issue already has a link to the source code. I was trying to find a better way instead of copy-paste the code from Go to NodeJs. anyways I couldn't and you basically confirmed for me that I won't find a better answer. so yes you can write an answer about that. I will also write an answer about the copy-paste from Go code to NodeJs code that check if a deployment failed/passed and how I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through k8s source code, I was able to implement this logic by my self in Node.js:

> How to make sure the new deployment succeed?

> How to make the the new deployment failed?

https://github.com/stavalfi/era-ci/blob/master/packages/steps/src/k8s/utils.ts#L387

Basically, I'm subscribing to events about a specific deplyoment (AFTER chancing something in it, for example, the image).

> Is it safe to assume that if the spec/containers/0/image changes to something different than what I'm expecting, it means there is a new deployment and I should stop watching?

Yes. But https://github.com/stavalfi/era-ci/blob/master/packages/steps/src/k8s/utils.ts#L62 will help also to idenfity that there is a new deployment going on and the yours is no longer the "latest-deployment".

---

For More Info
I wrote an answer about how deployment works under the hood: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66092577/806963

Answer (score 0):

As we have discussed in comment section I have mentioned that to check any object and processes in Kubernetes you have to use kubectl - see: [kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/).
Take a look how to execute proper command to gain required information - [kubectl-rollout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#rollout).
If you want to check how rollout process looks from backgroud look at the source code - [src-code-rollout-kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/rollout/rollout.go).

Pay attention on that if you are using `node-api`:

> The node-api group was migrated to a built-in API in the > [k8s.io/api](https://github.com/kubernetes/api) repo with the v1.14
> release. This repo is no longer maintained, and no longer synced
> with core kubernetes as of the v1.18 release.

Answer (score -1):

I often use 2 following command for check out deployment status

```
kubectl describe deployment <your-deployment-name>
kubectl get deployment <your-deployment-name> -oyaml
```

The first will show you some events about process of schedule a deployment.

The second is more detailed. It contains all of your deployment's resource info as yaml format.

Is that enough for your need ?

Comment: thanks but as I mentioned, I'm using k8s node api to communicate with k8s so I need to know what kubectl does, because I'm not using kubectl.